# Why am I getting crackling / popping with my LM386 audio amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio

I am trying to diagnose why my LM386 (250mW version) audio amplifier is crackling when the volume is more than a few mV. I created the circuit according to the diagram on the datasheet with pin 7 and 8 floating and no variable resistor (signal from 3.5mm mono cable directly into pin 3). I did the following:

- Used a "star grounding pattern" with all grounds connected to a common point next to the ground pin of the chip
- Used a shielded 3.5mm mono cable
- Tried adding a 250uF and 1000uF power supply decoupling capacitor
- Tried changing the 250uF decoupling output capacitor to 1000uF
- Tried a different speaker (4 ohm and 8 ohm)
- Tried a different power supply
- Tried removing the Zobel RC Filter
- Power Supply is 12V / 120W

None of the above made a difference. Only when playing audio at very low (almost inaudible) volume does the crackling disappear. This is the output from the speaker:

[image]

This is the prototyped board:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your supply voltage? How much current can your power supply offer?

Comment: Ceramic decoupling cap?

Comment: @MarcusMüller 12V, the SMPS can supply 120W.

Comment: @Mattman944 electrolytic for both. Only the Zobel capacitor is ceramic

Comment: LM386 circuits are very prone to oscillation. The design is very old, and there are better parts available now.  Layout is very important. Avoid long leads on components. Always apply decoupling per the datasheet (as indicated in other comments / answers). Avoid long input and output leads. Unless you are strongly wedded to this part, I suggest buying a cheap Chinese amplifier module using a more modern device.

Comment: Looks like there might be an unintended stray copper strand (i.e. a short) between pin 6 (Vs) and 7 (bypass), but it’s hard to make out clearly.

Comment: My first thought when seeing the soldering was "oh dear!"

Answer (score 1):

Place a 47 nF capacitor across the IC's power supply as the [spec sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) says, fig. 22.

[image]

Comment: The AC coupling input cap Cc shown in this diagram would probably also be a good idea.

Comment: The supply bypass capacitor should be placed very close to the chip, directly from pin 6 to pin 4.